Pass secrets to custom action
I am creating my own custom action.
I want to be able to pass a secret to it, so I have the following declaration at the top of the file:
secrets:
  MY_SECRET:
    description: A secret that this action needs
    required: true

I am invoking it as follows:
        - name: test my action
          uses: MyOrg/my-repo/.github/actions/my_action@main
          with:
            something: someimput
          secrets:
            MY_SECRET: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET }}

this fails with:
The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/my_invoking_workflow.yaml (Line: 63, Col: 11): Unexpected value 'secrets'

How can I safely pass secrets to a custom action?

Custom actions don't have secrets, just inputs: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#about-yaml-syntax-for-github-actions.

Custom actions don't have secrets but can receive secrets via "input".
Add an input for the secret in your custom action:
name: My Action

inputs:
  my_secret:
    description: 'My Secret'
    required: true

run:
  using "composite"
  steps:
    - name: Do something with my secret
      shell: bash
      run: echo ${{ inputs.my_secret }}

Pass the secret (created previously in Settings > Secrets and variables) when you call the custom action:
my_job:
  steps:
    - name: Execute some custom action
      uses: My_Org/My_Repo/.github/actions/My_Action@main
      with:
        my_secret = {{ secrets.MY_SECRET }}


You're trying to pass secrets as input to calling workflow, this will not work.
try something below
on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
     my_var1:
        required: false
        type: string
        default: false
        description: "If my_var1 is required"

and then you can call using
 - name: test my action
   uses: MyOrg/my-repo/.github/actions/my_action@main
   with:
    my_var1: "my_value"

but if you want to pass secrets then no need to define it your custom action instead you can specify secrets: inherit from the calling workflow.
 - name: test my action
   uses: MyOrg/my-repo/.github/actions/my_action@main
   secrets: inherit

you can access secrets in the calling workflow.

The question is about inputs and secrets for an action, not a reusable workflow. Even with inherit, you still have to pass the secret as an input to the action itself.
